# What is the best way to set AngularJS $provide.constant values from a C# MVC Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an AngularJS application with a .NET MVC/WebAPI backend. I have one MVC action that serves up my main HTML page that loads my AngularJS app. This MVC action loads several application settings from the Web.config as well as the database and returns them to the view as a model. I'm looking for a good way to set those MVC `Model` values as `$provide.constant` values in my AngularJS `.config` method.

MVC Controller method:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var model = new IndexViewModel {
        Uri1 = GetUri1(),
        Uri2 = GetUri2()
        //...etc
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

My MVC _Layout.cshtml:

```
@model IndexViewModel
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/content/css")
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        @if (Model != null)    //May be null on error page
        {
            <text>
                var modelExists = true;
                var uri1 = '@Model.Uri1';
                var uri2 = '@Model.Uri2';
            </text>
        }
        else
        {
            <text>
                var modelExists = false;
            </text>
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Body omitted -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular", "~/bundles/app") //Loads angular library and my application
</body>
```

app.js:

```
"use strict";
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .config(['$provide' '$window', function ($provide, $window) {
        if ($window.modelExists){
            $provide.constant('const_Uri1', $window.uri1);
            $provide.constant('const_URi2', $window.uri2);
        }            
    }]);
```

This is a vastly simplified version of my code but I think it illustrates my concern. Is there a better or standard way of doing this that I am overlooking? I don't like the code in my `_Layout.cshtml` because I have many more configuration values.

Comment: instead of individual variables , pass an object with those variables as properties. Then all you need is the object reference in your app

Comment: Do you mean set the constant as an object with properties? As far as I am aware, AngularJS $provide.constant values cannot have properties.

Comment: I mean something like `var appConfig={ modelExists:true, ur1: '@Model.Uri1'..}`.   Constant can be an object also, but you also have access to that data anywhere simply due to global namespace also

Comment: i might be wrong about constant can be object but numerous other ways to pass the config object i suggested into the app...`value`, through a service, create a provider etc

Comment: Right, I've been accessing the variables now via $window.uri1 but I don't like that because it pollutes the window space. I agree that your suggestion to make appConfig an object definitely makes window cleaner but I was hoping there would be a better way.

Comment: can always create a service that gets the data using $http

Comment: You cannot inject a service into module.config, only providers.

Comment: right, I wasn't sure how critical the data is right at run time. To me one object in window namespace isn't really poluting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a bunch of config values and you don't mind an extra network call, one way to do this is to create an MVC view that returns the settings as an Angular constant...

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

// ...

public ActionResult Settings(string angularModuleName = "myApp")
{
    var settings = new 
    {
        uri1 = GetUri1(),
        uri2 = GetUri1()
        // ...
    };

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(settings);

    var settingsVm = new SettingsViewModel
    {
        SettingsJson = json,
        AngularModuleName = angularModuleName
    };

    Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
    return View(settingsVm);
}
```

In the Razor view...

```
@model MyApp.SettingsViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

(function (app) {
    app.constant('settings', @Html.Raw(Model.SettingsJson));
})(angular.module('@Model.AngularModuleName'));
```

In the pages that need the files, just add a script tag to bring in the constants...

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular", "~/bundles/app") //Loads angular library and my application
<script src="/home/settings?appname=foo"></scripts>
```

This will return the script...

```
(function (app) {
    app.constant('settings', {
        "uri1": "https://uri1",
        "uri2": "https://uri2"
    });
})(angular.module('foo'));
```

Now you can inject the `settings` service anywhere in your Angular code. Nothing is leaked into the global scope.

You can also use this technique to inject the settings directly into a particular HTML view, but I generally prefer to split it out so that it is included only when needed.

Comment: I like this idea a lot and I'm trying it out, however I don't see a `JavaScriptSerializer` class. I don't even see a `System.Web.Scripts` reference to add. Where is that coming from?

Comment: It's `System.Web.Script` and it should be in `System.Web.Extensions`, I believe. Depending on the web project template, that dll might already be referenced. Also, if you're already using JSON.NET, you can just use that to serialize.

Comment: I just used JSON.NET to serialize it. Thanks Anthony, I really like this solution and it's helped me clean up my app considerably.

Comment: just what I was looking for, and for exactly the same reason. +1

Comment: Awesome! I've since blogged about this in slightly more detail, and started using the same technique for client side localiation (serializing resx files for angular)... http://anthonychu.ca/post/how-to-pass-webconfig-settings-to-angularjs

Comment: @AnthonyChu great blog article. very helpful.